# How the end user use the decentralise applicaton?

Tags: metamask, dapp-development, rinkeby

I am new to ethereum blockchain. I created a decentralise application for token sell.I deployed it smart contract into Rinkeby test network.I also hosted it into github pages.When end user use it application so,it is necessary to use Meta-mask extension for web3 provider to connect application to ethereum block-chain.

So,One question in my mind,**when we create decentralize applications.Is is necessary to use metamask who use decentralise application??**

**And if end user not use metamask.How transaction and dapps connect to the blockchain.Can we create custom web3 provider like metamask. So end user not use metamask when he/she use decentralise application??**

It might be a silly question but here i want to understand this concept more deeply.

Please help to clear my above query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it is not necessary to use Metamask to use decentralized applications.
Metamask is "Web3js + HD Wallet". 
it means end users have not to worry about signing transactions (remembering private keys), whereas decentralised application developers can use exposed Web3js functionality.

As an decentralized developer you can embed your own web3js to interact with ethereum node, and your application could ask private key from end users to sign transactions.

**But**, asking private keys from end users can be a big security risk.

Comment: But end-user have not enough either.So how he has completed his  transactions??

Comment: No, if end user doesn't have enough ethers, he won't be able to make transactions, with or without Metamask.

Comment: So,I want to how end user will get enough ether to use my decentralise application

Comment: In summary "Decentralized applications is a smart contract deployed on ethereum blockchain and a frontend to use that smart contract" .  If user want to use your smart contract they require ethers.(they have to buy additional ethers, if not enough present)

Comment: if you are statisfied with answer, would you mind upvoting and marking answer as correct.

Comment: Hi kherwa, I want build decentralise application like twitter(chat application).So how end user it.and In this case user also have enough either to use application.

Comment: Visit leeroy.io , it’s same decentralised application, you want to build.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79012/discussion-between-anupam-jain-and-kherwa).